# What is the correct way to use UserIdentity?

Tags: authentication

I am planning to create a [micropub](http://indiewebcamp.com/micropub) plugin so that any micropub client can post to craft, particularly useful for automatic data logging and mobile clients. But I am trying to work out the best way to authenticate.

I have read through the [UserIdentity](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/users/UserIdentity) docs but I was wondering if anybody has an examples of how to use it correctly?

Comment: I should note that micropub uses IndieAuth (similar to OpenID) and therefore the plugin will not have the password to authenticate with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic user identity relies on login and password, so you will have to create your own class to represent an identity based on something else, like a token for example:

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

class TokenIdentity extends UserIdentity
{
    private $_id;
    public $token;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $socialUser = craft()->social->getUserByEncodedToken($this->token);

        if($socialUser) {
            $this->_id = $socialUser->user->id;
            $this->username = $socialUser->user->username;
            $this->errorCode = static::ERROR_NONE;

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to create your own user session service to be able to authenticate the user (with a token for example):

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

class Social_UserSessionService extends UserSessionService {

    private $_identity;
    public $allowAutoLogin = true;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setStateKeyPrefix(md5('Yii.Craft\UserSessionService.'.craft()->getId()));

        parent::init();
    }

    public function login(Oauth_TokenModel $token)
    {
        $rememberMe = true;

        $this->_identity = new TokenIdentity($token->encodedToken);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();

        // Was the login successful?
        if ($this->_identity->errorCode == TokenIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
        {
            // Get how long this session is supposed to last.

            $this->authTimeout = craft()->config->getUserSessionDuration($rememberMe);

            $id = $this->_identity->getId();

            $user = craft()->users->getUserById($id);

            $states = $this->_identity->getPersistentStates();


            // Run any before login logic.
            if ($this->beforeLogin($id, $states, false))
            {
                // Fire an 'onBeforeLogin' event
                $this->onBeforeLogin(new Event($this, array(
                    'username'      => $user->username,
                )));

                $this->changeIdentity($id, $this->_identity->getName(), $states);

                // Fire an 'onLogin' event
                $this->onLogin(new Event($this, array(
                    'username'      => $user->username,
                )));

                if ($this->authTimeout)
                {
                    if ($this->allowAutoLogin)
                    {
                        if ($user)
                        {
                            // Save the necessary info to the identity cookie.
                            $sessionToken = StringHelper::UUID();
                            $hashedToken = craft()->security->hashData(base64_encode(serialize($sessionToken)));
                            $uid = craft()->users->handleSuccessfulLogin($user, $hashedToken);

                            $data = array(
                                $this->getName(),
                                $sessionToken,
                                $uid,
                                ($rememberMe ? 1 : 0),
                                craft()->request->getUserAgent(),
                                $this->saveIdentityStates(),
                            );

                            $this->saveCookie('', $data, $this->authTimeout);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception(Craft::t('Could not find a user with Id of {userId}.', array('{userId}' => $this->getId())));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception(Craft::t('{class}.allowAutoLogin must be set true in order to use cookie-based authentication.', array('{class}' => get_class($this))));
                    }
                }

                $this->afterLogin(false);
            }

            return !$this->getIsGuest();
        }

        Craft::log('Tried to log in unsuccessfully.', LogLevel::Warning);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code comes from a plugin which is still under development so don't take for granted it's all secure or the best way to achieve this, but hopefully it will help you get started !

Comment: I was planning to use tokens, so this looks like the perfect place to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What about setting up a relation between your CustomUserAuthModel and the UserModel, check if everything is alright through your plugin with IndieAuth, and then login, through UserSessionService->impersonate()?

```
The new user session will only last as long as the browser session remains active; no identity cookie will be * created.
```

Not sure if that will work for you, but might be worth a try?

Comment: I didn't know about impersonate, that could be quite useful thanks!